Is a 1500w inverter suitable for a 10a portable band saw?
I have a DEWALT Portable Band Saw, 10 Amp [1200 watts] (DWM120K):

I'm considering buying a MotoMaster 1500W Power Inverter:

Use case: Cutting 1/4" thick, 2"x2" mild steel tube in the woods using power from a 2010 Silverado 1500 truck. A generator would be handy, but the benefit of an inverter is that it's smaller and doesn't need gas, so I could keep it in the truck in the future and always have it with me if needed. An inverter is also cheaper than a generator.

Question:
I don't see the amperage listed on the inverter website. I'm inexperienced with electrical, but best guess is the amperage is 12.5 amps (1500w and 120v = 12.5a). Does that mean the inverter is suitable for the band saw?

Not sure if inverters have an over amperage safety factor for motors starting.  Like breakers and generators do.  Starting of motors can be a few factors over the ten amp running rating for a second or two.

So will the truck be running, or are you thinking you will use the truck battery alone? Perhaps a good battery box with a 2000W inverter might be a better way to go. Build your own, or buy from one of many vendors. Or trade in for a battery-powered band saw (I have one that would make light work of such tubing).

Following on from @JonCuster's point,if you're not running the engine, what's plan B for if you flatten the battery in the middle of the woods?  I'd say you have 2 options: (i) get a 2nd battery (ideally one designed for deeper discharge than a car battery), charge that off the engine (and/or solar if you've something to put the panel on, noting that it will take a while to charge).  Or (ii) run the engine. I'd line up the work, start the engine, do all the cuts, and leave the engine on for a few minutes afterwards if you've been cutting solidly

The link provided shows power use at 1200 Watts for the tool, while the inverter specs reference 3000 Watts peak/surge. I think it's a go.

@ChrisH - these days having a jump pack in your truck in the woods is a pretty good idea anyway, but planning on having to use it is bad form...

@JonCuster yes, and I'm told by someone who does that sort of thing for a living that the new mini ones are pretty good. That's a long story involving an EV with a full main battery but me flattening the small 12V battery that's used to run the startup routine.  We weren't exactly in the woods, but I had to run 4½ miles to get another vehicle, arriving just as the mechanic did.  Of course my phrasing was designed to provoke thinking about failure modes

If you didn't already have tool(s) purchased, I might suggest going with tools with rechargeable battery packs, as those could charge over time with a much lower instantaneous current draw at the charger that could be easily done off your truck.   You could also have multiple batteries charged up off of 120V chargers ahead of time.  But if the 120V tool(s) are already purchased, than this would likely be a non-starter in your situation.

Probably. Maybe.
1500 watts divided by 120 volts gets you 12.5 amps as you figured, but that's assuming you only need 10 amps even under load, and that the inverter will perform as claimed.
You may need something with more overhead capacity, but you won't know until you try. If you're gentle with the tool it may work fine.

Agreed. Only thing to possibly consider is if future use cases involve running sensitive electronics, as opposed to motors or transformers. Then you’d want to consider a more expensive pure sine inverter.

Saw someone with a fridge rated at 3A running that would not start on a "10A" rated inverter due to the starting inrush current. So "probably not" is likely...

My 1500W inverter (used once!) is rated 3000W peak for precisely this reason - it can only handle a very short peak.  Even that ratio clearly wouldn't help in the case @SolarMike is thinking of

A compressor takes quite a bit more kick than a simple motor. I have more hope for this tool than I would for a fridge.

Yeah, starting the motor up unloaded and going very slow with the feed has a much better chance of working than a compressor starting into significant pressure

Using a motor startup current calculator, with perfect power factor and efficiency (i.e., both values = 1 instead of more realistic values like .84 and .9), and with the advertised 1200 Watts of running (not startup) power at 120V, the startup current would be 23.09 Amps. With pf=.84 and efficiency=.9 instead of them both being 1, the calculator yields 30.55 Amps on startup. Assuming you start the bandsaw unloaded (i.e., not trying to cut anything while starting up the motor), this high inrush current should last less than a second, maybe three seconds max, since it will reach full speed (Locked Rotor Torque) in that time period. The current will gradually decrease to standard operating current. If the inrush current lasts only about half a second, I wouldn't be too worried, but I'd be a tiny bit more worried that small wires' (if they exist here) insulation would get fried if it lasted longer than 3 seconds. As for whether there's even enough current to start the device, the advertised surge current provided by the inverter is 3000W. Using P=IV, that gives an instantaneous (i.e., looking at a singular point in time) current of 3000W/120V = 25A. Though 23.09 Amps (ideal) < 25 Amps, 30.55 Amps (practical) is not less than 25 Amps, so there's likely not quite enough startup current to get your bandsaw running, unless your vehicle supplies extra power (like by spinning the alternator faster by "giving your vehicle gas") and the inverter somehow deals with it in a way that increases your surge current output.
P = IV -> I = P/V -> Current = Watts/Volts -> 1200Wbandsaw/120V = 10A (of load, not supply).
Environmental factors:

Dust buildup reducing heat transference away from the bandsaw motor -> the motor wiring heats up more, meaning it will draw somewhat less than 10 Amps (by how much? I can't say aside from "probably not a huge difference") due to the higher wire resistance (V=IR: if R increases while V stays constant, I must decrease)
However, once the "blade" dulls, you'll probably push the blade holder so that it has more pressure to cut with, which places more physical resistance on the motor, which brings it more out of phase, which draws more current (same principle as startup current where the physical rotation speed doesn't keep up with the electrical "rotation speed" (phase)); this is a far more significant factor to current draw than the motor heating up a bit.
As the other answers/comments mention, if you baby how much material you feed into it (decrease the load), you should be fine (barely).
There's often corrosion on people's vehicular battery terminals and lots of vehicle parts can somewhat deal with having undervoltage (meaning nobody fixes the problem because it doesn't look like there's a problem). Make sure there's a strong electrical connection and no corrosion first, to make sure that the inverter is receiving enough current to produce 120V. Supplying too little voltage for the same load means excess current is drawn (P=IV: if P remains constant and V decreases, I must increase), which could fry your vehicle battery or inverter or bandsaw.

tl;dr Your bandsaw will probably work (once you get it to start moving), but be careful with how far you push your bandsaw.

It's going to depend on how the inverter deals with overload. The instantaneous start up current of a tool before the motor starts to move can easily exceed 20x running current, really just limited by the current carrying capacity of the wires feeding the motor. A motor will start with current less than current calculated by resistance, it will just flatten and extend the curve.  So the question is how long will the protective circuitry of the inverter allow delivery of rated surge current before tripping?
A contractor I worked for put good 1800 watt inverters in most of their 200 service trucks. Those inverters would run any tool in the truck.
Looking at inverter shown and not being able to see product reviews to see if this fits into the category of good quality, the only research option I see is clicking back a page to show more inverters sold by CT, then sorting by 4-star or better, and this inverter is still shown.
But at this price point if I bought this and tried to return it because it didn't work I would probably be red from embarrassment, not anger.
